# How to limit results between two parties in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, limit

I have the below MySQL query, but I am looking to limit the result to recent 5 conversations between the same starter and responder (I have a auto incrementing ID column and also a timestamp column if that helps), how would I achieve this? Simply adding LIMIT 5 to the end - will limit all results.

```
SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE starter = '%d' OR responder = '%d'
```

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: What does `limit all results` mean? You want conversations between a particular pair which the query plus a limit clause will give you. What else do you need? What goes wrong by adding the limit clause?

Comment: Do you mean to select the 5 latest conversations between those two people? Or just the last 5 conversations, involving any of them? Or those where the starter is the same as the responder? Or do you mean the last 5 conversations of one person, whichever side they're on?

Comment: Maintain your data in two tables. For starter and responder. That will be easy way.

Comment: @Tordek the 5 latest conversions between those two people (so the results will show up to 5 for each person who has had a conversation with a certain person - which I will specify). Thanks.

Comment: Please add an example of what you expect to get, because you seem to be saying two different things.

Comment: does it matter who the responder and who the starter is, so long as they are the same 2 people?? The devil's in the details

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could have 3 users, A, B, and C, and A may talk to B 50 times, and B to C 50 times, but in your result you want up to 5 conversations between A and B, plus up to 5 between B and C, and so on? If that is the case, then it's not really possible.

Comment: @Tordek Exactly! e.g. if I have 15 different conversations in my DB all of which the specified party is either a starter or responder, I want to only return the latest 5 between the specified party and the other party. So in my results there won't ever be the specified party and another party more then 5 times - but the total results could of course exceed 5.

Comment: @Drew please see above comment to Tordek.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
ORDER BY (name of your date column) DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

To the end of your current query